# Auth0 - How to get userID ? StatusCode400 Error

Tags: django, auth0

Happy Sundays everyone.

Note: Setup is Django-Rest.

So I was trying to get user ID because I am going to check the user's roles in the login, and decide whether let them in or not. So currently I can get some information as

```
id_token = token.get('id_token')
jwk_set = oauth.auth0.fetch_jwk_set()
user_info = jwt.decode(id_token, jwk_set)
print(user_info)
```

However, this information has 'nickname, name, picture, email' and so on. Therefore I tried,

```
def get_user_id():
    import http.client

    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("cageda.eu.auth0.com")

    headers = { 'authorization': "Bearer {settings.SOCIAL_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN}" }

    conn.request("GET", "/api/v2/users/USER_ID", headers=headers)

    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()

    print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

However, this is returning as:

```
{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Bad HTTP authentication header format","errorCode":"Bearer"}
```

I am totally stuck. A help would be a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your headers incorrectly it should be `headers = {'authorization': "Bearer " + settings.SOCIAL_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN}` not `headers = { 'authorization': "Bearer {settings.SOCIAL_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN}" }`

```
def get_user_id():
    import http.client
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("cageda.eu.auth0.com")
    headers = {'authorization': "Bearer " + settings.SOCIAL_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN}
    conn.request("GET", "/api/v2/users/USER_ID", headers=headers)
    
    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()
    print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Try this and see if it works. I suggest using `Postman` to verify the response of your bearer token and API endpoint.